# JDO Exception in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

```
       My google app engine project working fine last 4 months but today i have faced a strange Error like " i have not change any jar and library last four months related to jdo . could anyone explain me suddenly what happened to Google app engine and how to fix it.   Error is
```

org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper getJDOExceptionForNucleusException: Exception thrown
    Persistent class "Class com.zeronebyte.domain.MYUser does not seem to have been enhanced. You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.

```
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager.getDatastoreClass(DatastoreManager.java:551)
    at
```

Any Help

Comment: So your class is not enhanced, so suggest that you enhance it using the documented ways of enhancing classes for GAE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen whenever there is a change in the database table related class files.
It is a technique for byte-code manipulation to make the normal Java classes "persistable". The mechanism provided by DataNucleus is to use an "enhancer" process to perform this manipulation before you use your classes at runtime. Read more: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/enhancer.html

How to fix it:
For eclipse: details are here: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/guides/eclipse.html#enhancer

If you are using Ant build then open build.xml and run the target "enhancer".